# ROPC passwords invalid

Tags: passwords, azure-ad-b2c

I just wanted to ask for assistance on the following. My client has enabled an ROPC flow and it works properly most of the time.
It is hard to record the error but we made it.

https://msit.microsoftstream.com/video/2340a1ff-0400-a521-2f90-f1eac84c3b02
Check from min 20 for the error.

There are invalid passwords like the following that doesn't work.
`Ac@grra%42`, `Acgrra%42`, `Ac@gr%ra%42`.

Passwords that worked properly were the following:
`Vg#5k4VrMw`, `&wy6S"-s'&`, `Micro%s0ft`.

Is there any password policy or anything that may cause this behavior?

Comment: we don't have permissions to view the recording. Please try to share proper error messages.

Comment: Hello Raghavendra, the error we get is invalid username or password. I'm not sure if there is any limitation on the passwords or password consideration to take when it comes to the password syntax or something. As you can see, there were really complex passwords and they worked properly. Then, the password Ac@grra%42 didn't work, not even by adding or removing characters. I'm available on teams to check further.

Comment: This is a bug that we are fixing. We will update here when it is fixed and the fix is ready to test.